# When clicking a cell, my app throws a NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I am kind of a novice to programming and I thought I could find help here.

I am trying to make an app where when you click on the table view cell, it shows more detailed information.  When you click the cell, the debug area opens up and I am given the following message:

> 2013-07-15 12:41:19.261 Chevy[3909:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "ToB-mL-k5t-view-Ref-qb-iy9" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1c99012 0x10d6e7e 0x1c98deb 0x24a357 0xfbff8 0xfc232 0xfc4da 0x1138e5 0x1139cb 0x113c76 0x113d71 0x11489b 0x114e93 0x8ef23f7 0x114a88 0x470e63 0x462b99 0x462c14 0xca249 0xca4ed 0xad45b3 0x1c58376 0x1c57e06 0x1c3fa82 0x1c3ef44 0x1c3ee1b 0x1bf37e3 0x1bf3668 0x1affc 0x212d 0x2055)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  I can post some of my code if you'd like.

Comment: It's amazing that the compiler managed to produce a runtime UI error like that.  The compiler must be getting pretty sophisticated!

Comment: (Hint:  Read the message.  What you specified when creating your UITableViewController was not a valid NIB.)

Comment: What does that mean? Could you explain more?

Comment: Inside of your storyboard the `view` outlet of the UITableViewController is connected to something that is not a UITableView.

Comment: Try to also check out the free Sensible TableView framework, should make your life a lot easier as a novice.

Answer (score 0):

The IBOutlet is either disconnected in the xib file for the tableView or connected to some unwanted element.

Comment: When I open the storyboard file, I have the table view, called "Chevy Table View Controller" connected to a view controller, called "Chevy Detail View Controller" with a push segue.  Is there something I'm missing?